# Query on "Certificate of qualification (trade occupations)" - Express Entry

Tags: canada, immigration, resident-permit

In this [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp), I would like to understand the meaning of "Certificate of qualification (trade occupations)".

For NOC code - 2713("Software Engineer"), What kind of certification is required despite one has 3+ years of relavant industry experience with bachelor's and master's degree in Computer Science & Engineering? Please clarify!!

Comment: as far as i know, the best certificate for `software engineer` roles globally is doing bachelor's or master's in CompScience Engineering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/trades/applications.asp) for Canada's definition of trade occupations for 2014.

I'm not going to reproduce the entire list here, but extract some examples:

```
Chefs
Machinists
Plumbers
Mechanics
Fishermen/women
Manufacturing plant operators
etc.
```

Trade occupations do not include any occupation where the normal path to a job include a post-secondary or other academic degree.

Comment: "certificate of evaluation" doesn't exist. Do you mean "..of qualification"? That only counts if your job classification is a "trade", not a "professional" (white collar) job and is in exchange for not having post-secondary education. That is, if you're white collar, you can get points for post-secondary education and experience. If you're "blue collar", you can get points for having certification or trade school education and experience.

Comment: sorry, yes "certificate of qualification"